# Stretching cube object

Tags: python, game-engine

Stretching out Cube object in real time until it touch's any other object in the
scene.Is this possible in real-time.This cube object need's to stop once it hit any other object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling snapping? When I am modeling, I typically enable snapping and set the snap element to "Face" and it works for me.

[image]